# Vegas slider preload

Tags: javascript, background, slider

I would like to set the preload option to this vegas slider over here

http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/slideshow

But I know nothing about javascript, would someone please help me.

Comment: Review this tutorial first: http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Documentation on the right](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/slideshow/):

```
OPTION: PRELOAD
Preload all the images of the Slideshow.
```

It sounds like you have to use the `preload` parameter:

```
$.vegas('slideshow', {
  preload: true,
  backgrounds:[
    { src:'/img/background1.jpg' },
    { src:'/img/background2.jpg' },
    { src:'/img/background3.jpg' }
  ]
})('overlay');
```